# How to I update data from the table using ajax, jquery and php?

Tags: php, jquery

Can somebody help regarding to my PHP and jQuery? I try to change my password using PHP, jQuery and Ajax. I know this method is kind of weird. But I want to explore more about Ajax, jQuery with PHP. I want to UPDATE my password without showing or typing the current password. I want my textbox empty and if I input something it will change my password in my db table. Don't need to type my current password. My problem is it didn't update my password. How can I update my db password? depends who is login.

```
<?php 
     $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "mydb");
 if(isset($_POST["btnChange"])) {
        $checkUser = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE id= $_SESSION[id]");
        if ($checkUser->num_rows > 0) {
            $conn->query("UPDATE tbl_user SET password = '$_POST[new_password]' WHERE id= $_SESSION[id]");
            echo "Update Successfully!";
        }
    }
?>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#btnChange").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
   url:"insert.php",
   method:"post",
   data:{btnChange: "", new_password: $("#new_password").val(),},
   success: function(data){
    alert(data);
   }
  });
 });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="changeapasswordjs.js"></script>
        <title>Change password</title>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <h1>Change password</h1>
        <form id="simpleForm">
            <div>
                <label for="new_password">Your new_password</label>
                <input type="password" name="new_password" id="new_password" />
            </div> 
            <br>
            <div>
                <button id="btnChange">Change password</button>
            </div>    
        </form>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `header('Content-Type: application/json');` at the top of your PHP script, then use `json_encode()` to encode your output so your Javascript can read the output. Also, you need to concatenate your SQL. `....SET password = '" . $_POST['new_password'] . "' WHERE....`

Answer (score 0):

To access an array, the key must be in quotes like so `['key']`. Also, you can wrap `{}` around the variable to output it inside a string.

```
// First query you do
$checkUser = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE id = '{$_SESSION['id']}'");

// Second query you do
$conn->query("UPDATE tbl_user SET password = '{$_POST['new_password']}' WHERE id = '{$_SESSION['id']}'");
```

You're also missing the content type you're outputting and should encode your response in json:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode("Update Successfully!");
```

Furthermore, to access the super variable `$_SESSION` you must first use `session_start()` prior to accessing the variable.

Further, none question related but a key point moving on, your queries are prone to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1) and you should consider [turning error logging on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438060/showing-all-errors-and-warnings/13402590).

Comment: where do I put the `session_start()`?

Comment: At the top of your php file beneath `<?php` and above `$conn = ...`

Comment: `Undefined index: id`

Comment: `POST http://localhost/foldername/change.php 404 (Not Found) jquery.js:4`

Comment: Your errors are self-explained, `$_SESSION['id']` is empty, you haven't yet set it and `change.php` does not exist in the current directory, you must put the absolute path to where the file exists

Comment: how can I set `$_SESSION['id']` ? I already solved the change.php

Comment: session_start(); $_SESSION['id'] = 1; // your value

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i think your code misses a very important statement which is the `session_start()` statement.

Secondly, the `id` session can't be called the way you are calling it in your code, you have to add quotes like this `$_SESSION['id']`.

You also need to add quotes in the `WHERE clause` so it becomes a valid statement like the following: `WHERE id = '$_SESSION['id']'`.
Again, you are accessing `$_POST` array the wrong way, you have to add the quotes like this `$_POST['new_password']`.

After correcting these mistakes, the final code should look like this:

```
<?php
session_start(); //Initializing session
     $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "mydb");
 if(isset($_POST["btnChange"])) {
        $checkUser = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE id='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
        if ($checkUser->num_rows > 0) {
            $conn->query("UPDATE tbl_user SET password = '".$_POST["new_password"]."' WHERE id='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
            echo "Update Successfully!";
        }
    }
?>
```

## UPDATE

Please reproduce the code to this, it is recommended to use an `else` statement in case the user doesn't exist.

```
 <?php
 session_start(); //Initializing session
      $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "mydb");
  if(isset($_POST["btnChange"])) {
         $checkUser = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE id='".$_SESSION['id']."'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
         if ($checkUser->num_rows > 0) {
             $conn->query("UPDATE tbl_user SET password = '".$_POST['new_password']."' WHERE id='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
             echo "ID: ".$_SESSION['id'];
         }
         else {
             echo "User doesn't exist.";
             echo "<br>ID: ".$_SESSION['id'];
         }
     }
 ?>
```

Comment: why it didn;t update my password? There something wrong with my jQuery and Ajax?

Comment: Try changing the `$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','mydb);'` to `$con = new mysqli('localhost','root','','mydb') or die(mysqli_error($con));` and see check if there is any mysqli errors

Comment: same sir no error and password didn't change at all.

Comment: Could you please add `echo '<br>ID: '.$_SESSION['id'];` to the `if($checkUser->num_rows >) statement` and tell me what is the the current output?
Also check if there are any spaces before the `session_start();` and delete them

Comment: This is the error in the alert box `<br>Parse error</b>: syntax error, unexpected '&quot;', expecting identifier (T_STRING)
or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in <b> C: xampp\htdocs\userAndAdmin/change.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br/>`

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check it out and comment the output.

Comment: Same error alert box show this message `<br>Parse error</b>: syntax error, unexpected '&quot;', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in <b> C: xampp\htdocs\userAndAdmin/change.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br/>`

Comment: my id is integer and my password is encrypted

Comment: Yeah, there really was syntax errors, i confused the usage of double quotes and single quotes, copy and paste the edited code again.